# Average cost per month for all the dataset. SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database table as shown below and i want to find the average cost per month for all the records in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE repairs( 
repair_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
cost NUMERIC(10,2) , 
start_date DATE NOT NULL ,   
);
```

I tried something as

```
SELECT AVG(cost) AS avg 
FROM ( SELECT count(*) AS count, MONTH(start_date) as mnth
       FROM repairs
       GROUP BY mnth) AS a
```

but there are some errors, 
is there any solution?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc...) that you are using.

Comment: First thing: there is no column called `cost` in the subquery

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want.  Your question suggests you want one value per month.  Your query returns one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*) AS count, 
DATE_TRUNC('month',start_date) as mnth, 
AVG(cost) AS avg 
FROM repairs
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('month', start_date);
```

This will group by month. You can truncate the timestamps/dates to whatever level you like: so day/week/quarter etc

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` clause only instead of `subquery` :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date) AS mnth, 
       AVG(cost) AS avg 
FROM repairs
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I tried that but is an error on MONTH(start_date) that says function month(date) does not exist

Comment: @pfc1995. . . Use `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date)`.